# Загрузки файлов на сервер с описанием

Tags: php, html

Всем привет. Недавно начал заниматься версткой и вот сверстал 1-й нормальный макет. Сейчас интересует одно, нужно сделать нормальные формы. Так вот ребята, у меня есть форма загрузки изображений на сервер с описанием, которое можно вводить, а можно и не вводить. Прошу я что? Прошу помочь в PHP кодом, который будет это все делать. То есть. Что имею.
Форму.

```
<form action="loadfile.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input id="load" name="load" type="file" size="59">
<input id="descrip" name="descrip" type="text" size="70.9">
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

И PHP скрипт loadfile.php, который просто загружает изображение на сервер без описания.

```
<?
if (empty($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])) die('Файл не принят сервером');
$tmp = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
$fname = $_FILES['img']['name'];
if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'file/image/'.$fname)) die('Не удалось переместить файл из временной папки');
echo '<img src="/file/image/'.$fname.'" />'; // картинка загружена
?>
```

От скрипта хочу, чтобы он заливал изображение на сервер и выводил то, что нужно мне с описанием, которое было введено при загрузке файла.
Я в PHP практически 0 так что... Помогите...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала надо описание сохранить.
**Есть несколько способов:**
 **1.** Забить в базу данных
 **2.** Создать файл и туда кидать описание
По другому описание будет показывать только в момент когда изображение загрузили.

```
 <?
    $des = $_POST['descrip'];
    if (empty($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])) die('Файл не принят сервером');
    $tmp = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
    $fname = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'file/image/'.$fname)) die('Не удалось переместить файл из временной папки');
    echo '<img src="/file/image/'.$fname.'" /><br />'.$des; // картинка загружена
    $fp = fopen ($fname.".txt", "w"); 
    fwrite($fp,$des);
    fclose($fp); 
    ?>
```

Это мы рассмотрели "Запись описание в файл". Если надо через sql то пишите.
А вывод элементарный через инклуд с название картинки и в конце *.txt, пример

```
include($fname.".txt");
```

Comment: Ну 1й способ мне не подходит, это точно.(Хост не позволяет)
2й - прекрасно подходит. Спасибо.
Я еще немного не понял, вы написали "Это мы рассмотрели "Запись описание в файл", а если смотреть на код скрипта, он загружает файл и выводит описание. (На сколько я понял) Или как?

Comment: Я имел виду, что я написал 2 вариант. Я не с России =)

Comment: Сейчас попробую его запустить.

Comment: неполучается что то у меня с формой...
Просто я недавно в врестке может что то не так...
Можно с вами связаться как-нибудь?

Comment: Мой скапй node_xaker, в других сетях редко сижу